# Quasi-isomorphism of injective complexes is a homotopy equivalence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homology-cohomology

Let $A^* = (0\rightarrow A^0\rightarrow A^1 \rightarrow ...), B^* = (0\rightarrow B^0\rightarrow B^1 \rightarrow ...)$ be complexes of injective objects of an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$. Suppose we have a quasi-isomorphism $f : A^* \rightarrow B^*$, i.e. the induced cohomology map $f^*:H^*(A^*) \rightarrow H^*(B^*)$ is an isomorphism. How do I show that $A^*$ and $B^*$ are homotopic, i.e. there exists $g: B^*\rightarrow A^*$ such that $gf \simeq 1_A$ and $fg \simeq 1_B$?

**My attempt**: So I tried to define $g: B^*\rightarrow A^*$ from the inverse $g^*: H^*(B^*)\rightarrow H^*(A^*)$ of $f^*$. Using
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
00 & \rightarrow & H^0(B^*) & \rightarrow & B^0\\
& & \downarrow & & \\
0 & \rightarrow & H^0(A^*) & \rightarrow & A^0 \\
\end{array}
\end{equation} 
I have that $g^0: B^0 \rightarrow A^0$ exists because $A^0$ is injective. Then I would like to say that if $g^0,g^1,...,g^{i-1}$ exist then $g^i$ must also exists:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
00 & \rightarrow & B^0 & \rightarrow & B^1 & \rightarrow & ... & \rightarrow & B^{i-1} &\rightarrow & B^i\\
& & \downarrow & & \downarrow & & & & \downarrow & & \\
0 & \rightarrow & A^0 & \rightarrow & A^1 & \rightarrow & ... & \rightarrow & A^{i-1} &\rightarrow & A^i \\
\end{array}
\end{equation} 
The problem is that $B^{i-1}\rightarrow B^i$ is not a monomorphism and I'm not sure how to continue from here.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that there are self maps between cochain complexes composed of injective modules that are not homotopic to the identity, but induce the identity on cohomology. This means that your proof must necessarily reference $f$ and not just $f^*$.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Could you explain more please? How can I construct $g$ from this?

Answer (score 3):

We consider the mapping cone $C(f)^i := A^{i+1}\oplus B^i$. The differentials of $C(f)$ is
\begin{equation}
D^i = \begin{pmatrix}
-d^{i+1}_A & 0\\ f^{i+1} & d^i_B
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Since $f^*:H^i(A^*)\rightarrow H^i(B^*)$ is an isomorphism for all $i$, by taking the long exact sequence of cohomology of
\begin{equation}
0\rightarrow B^* \rightarrow C(f)\rightarrow A[1]^*\rightarrow 0 
\end{equation}
we find that $H^i(C(f)^*) = 0, \forall i$, i.e. $C(f)$ is quasi-isomorphic to zero. But $A^i$ and $B^i$ are injective objects, so $C(f)^i$ is also injective as a finite coproduct (which is the same as product) of injective objects. So $C(f)$ is an injective resolution of $0$, just like the zero complex $0\rightarrow 0\rightarrow ...$ hence they are homotopic, i.e. $1_{C(f)} \simeq 0_{C(f)}$. This is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
1_{C(f)} = D^{i-1}\Sigma^i + \Sigma^{i+1}D^i
\end{equation}
for some morphism $\Sigma^*$. We can write $\Sigma^*$ in general as
\begin{equation}
\Sigma^i = \begin{pmatrix}
\Sigma_{AA}^i & \Sigma_{AB}^i\\ \Sigma^i_{BA} & \Sigma^i_{BB}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $\Sigma^i_{AA}: A^{i+1}\rightarrow A^i,\ \Sigma^i_{AB}:B^i\rightarrow A^i,\  \Sigma^i_{BA}: A^{i+1}\rightarrow B^{i-1},\ \Sigma^i_{BB}:B^i\rightarrow B^{i-1}$. Let $(a^{i+1},b^i)\in C(f)^i$. Then $(a^{i+1},b^i) = 1^i_{C(f)}(a^{i+1},b^i) = D^{i-1}\Sigma^i(a^{i+1},b^i) + \Sigma^{i+1}D^i(a^{i+1},b^i)$ gives
\begin{align}
a^{i+1} &= -d_A^i\Sigma_{AA}^ia^{i+1} - d_A^i\Sigma^i_{AB}b^i - \Sigma^{i+1}_{AA}d^{i+1}_Aa^{i+1} + \Sigma_{AB}^{i+1}f^{i+1}a^{i+1} + \Sigma_{AB}^{i+1}d^i_Bb^i\\
b^i &= f^i\Sigma_{AA}^ia^{i+1} + f^i\Sigma_{AB}^ib^i + d^{i-1}_B\Sigma^i_{BA}a^{i+1}+d_B^{i-1}\Sigma_{BB}^ib^i - \Sigma_{BA}^{i+1}d_A^{i+1}a^{i+1} + \Sigma_{BB}^{i+1}f^{i+1}a^{i+1} + \Sigma_{BB}^{i+1}d_B^ib^i.
\end{align}
Since $(a,b)$ is arbitrary, by setting $b = 0$ we get
\begin{align}
a^{i+1} - \Sigma_{AB}^{i+1}f^{i+1}a^{i+1} &= -d_A^i\Sigma_{AA}^ia^{i+1} - \Sigma^{i+1}_{AA}d^{i+1}_Aa^{i+1}\tag{1}\\
\Sigma_{BA}^{i+1}d_A^{i+1}a^{i+1} - d^{i-1}_B\Sigma^i_{BA}a^{i+1} &= f^i\Sigma_{AA}^ia^{i+1} + \Sigma_{BB}^{i+1}f^{i+1}a^{i+1}\tag{2}.
\end{align}
On the other hand, by setting $a = 0$ we get
\begin{align}
d_A^i\Sigma^i_{AB}b^i &= \Sigma_{AB}^{i+1}d^i_Bb^i\tag{3}\\
b^i - f^i\Sigma_{AB}^ib^i &= d_B^{i-1}\Sigma_{BB}^ib^i + \Sigma_{BB}^{i+1}d_B^ib^i\tag{4}.
\end{align}
Equation (3) shows that $g := \Sigma_{AB}^*:B^*\rightarrow A^*$ is a morphism of complexes.
Equation (1) and (4) shows that $gf\simeq 1_A$ and $fg \simeq 1_B$ respectively. Equation (2) seems to give an extra identity, but I don't think it is needed here.

Answer (score 1):

This is a direct consequence of Lemma 10.4.6 in Weibel's *Introduction to Homological Algebra* which roughly says

> If $A$ is a bounded below chain complex of injectives and $f \colon A \to B$ is a quasi-isomorphism then $f$ is left invertible in the homotopy category $K(\mathcal{A})$.

In your situation both $A$ and $B$ are bounded below complexes of injectives, so you can apply the lemma twice: In $K(\mathcal{A})$ the morphism $f$ is left invertible, and any left inverse $g$ of $f$ is a quasi-isomorphism and hence left invertible again. Now clearly (in any category) a morphism which has a left invertible left inverse is an isomorphism.

**Sketch of a proof of Lemma 10.4.6:** We may assume without loss of generality that $B$ is bounded below as well, say $A^i = B^i = 0$ for all $i \leq 1$. There is a canonical morphism $\varphi \colon C(f) \to A[1]$, where $C(f)$ denotes the mapping cone of $f$. Since $f$ is a quasi-isomorphism, $C(f)$ is exact, and so can be regarded as a resolution of $C(f)^0 = 0$. As a morphism between a resolution and a chain complex of injectives, $\varphi$ is uniquely determined up to homotopy by $\varphi^0$ which is the zero map. Hence $\varphi$ is null-homotopic, say by a homotopy $(t_i,g_i) \colon A^{i+1} \oplus B^i \to A^i$. Now you can check that $g$ is a morphism $B \to A$ and that $g \circ f$ is equivalent to the identity map witnessed by the homotopy $t$.